# Purpose of options.AutomaticAuthenticate with UseJwtBearerAuthentication

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

After updating a codebase from ASP 5 beta 7 to RC1-final, I began receiving this exception from the JwtBearer middleware

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

The determining factor I can see so far appears to be the setting of  options.AutomaticAuthenticate.  If it's `true`, then I get the exception, otherwise, I do not.

What is AutomaticAuthenticate and why would I need to enable it?

```
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true; 
    }
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload.GetIntClaim(String claimType)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload.get_Nbf()
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.<InitializeAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Api.Startup.<<Configure>b__9_0>d.MoveNext() in ...\Startup.cs:line 156
```

**Update on root cause**

Our codebase was creating duplicate claims for nbf, exp, and iat.  That explains why get_Nbf is in the stack trace and the complaint about "JArray" since each of those values was an array instead of a value.

Comment: Had this exact same problem.  We explicitly injected the nbf, exp and iat claims and the library injected another set so it started throwing errors.  It should really check to see if they're already there :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If its set to `true` then the middleware will run on every inbound request, look for a JWT token and if one is present it will validate it, and if valid create an identity from it and add it to the current user.

If its `false` that doesn't happen and you need to request the middleware to set an identity by specifying the bearer's scheme in your authorize attribute.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "YourBearerSchemeName")]
```

Or you set this in policy;

```
options.AddPolicy("RequireBearer", policy =>
{
    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("YourBearerSchemeName");
    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

});
```

So, by setting it to false you aren't actually running the bearer stuff until you ask for it, you're only putting the exception off until later.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my original question.  Guess what I'm stuck on, is what has changed between beta7 and rc1 to cause this? What exactly is being validated? The stack trace shows it's trying to convert something to int32.  Suppose I can try reproduce via a unit test in the JwtBearer source...

Comment: @Ken looks like your JWT token is malformed. Any chance you could share it?

Comment: That was my initial thought.  However, JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken() reads the token string just fine.  It JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken() that it crashes on.  I will try to create a minimal repro solution.

Comment: @blowdart Why if `AutomaticAuthenticate = true` it will try to authenticate all request, even if there is no `[Authorize]` attribute on controller or even if `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute applied? This is looks a bit strange from performance point of view - doing unnecessary things when they not needed.